# componentDidMount and constructor

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, callback, components, es6-promise

```
 class ProductsIndex extends Component {

   constructor (props){
     super(props);

     console.log(this) // #1. this logs ProductsIndex component

     fetch('someUrl')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(this)) // #2. this logs ProductsIndex component

     fetch('someUrl')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(console.log)  // #3. this logs [{..},{..},{..},{..}]
   }


   componentDidMount(){
     fetch('someUrl')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(console.log)  // #4. this logs [{..},{..},{..},{..}]

   }
```

As shown in the code above, both #1 and #2 point to same ***this***. And also as shown, both #3 and #4 returns **same** array. However, why the code below doesn't work??

```
 class ProductsIndex extends Component {

   constructor (props){
     super(props);

     fetch('someUrl')
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(arr => {
          this.state = {
              array: arr
          }
       })
    }
```

It throws an error saying that **this.state** is **null** and I really don't understand why.

Below code is the solution. could anyone please explain what exactly the difference is??

```
 class ProductsIndex extends Component {

   constructor (props){
     super(props);

     this.state = {
       array: []
     }
   }

   componentDidMount(){
      fetch('someUrl')
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(arr => {
            this.setState({
                array: arr
             })
          })
    }
```

Comment: Which line in the code is giving error **this.state is null ** , the approach of using request inside the constructor is not advisable to design. But I implemented the same code https://codesandbox.io/s/z2641rm9l3 which does not give any error. Please let us know

Comment: I tried to render() { return this.state.array.map( element => <p>{ element.title }</p>) } but it simply does not recognize **this** and now I know why.. I was confused and it was not very reasonable question after all. sorry :)

Answer (score 16):

The Problem is that when you place an async request in `constructor`, the `promise` might be resolved after `render` phase has executed  and at that point this.state is null and also since you just assign

```
this.state = {
    array: arr
}
```

and this won't lead to a re-render and so the component won't reflect the change. Having said that you should place your async requests in `componentDidMount`  which you mention in your second attempt, and since you call `setState` there, a `re-render` is triggered and the state in reflected in `render`

Comment: How about using `setState` in the constructor?

Comment: Don’t: Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions. Do not set state by using setState() in the constructor.

Comment: @JayDesai Care to explain why? Or just because it is generally bad to cause "side effects" in constructors?

Comment: use setState in componentDidMount. Static values, without previous asynchrnous action could pass in contructor this.state = {someInitValue: 1} . Link https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting - constructor is called first. You could not call this.setState in constructor.